# "bound method": How to create a file name in sub directory with python

Tags: python, class, directory

I try to create file with a random name in sub directory, but I've got this error:

```
 URL/<bound method webSiteCompanies.nameGenerator of
 <__main__.webSiteCompanies instance at 0x7fc30dbccd88>>
```

my code look like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import string
import random


class webSiteCompanies():

    def __init__(self):
        self.path = "URL"
        self.stringSize = 42

    def nameGenerator(self):
        chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
        return str(''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(self.stringSize)))


    def createFile(self):
        realPath = self.path + "/" + str(self.nameGenerator)
        try:
            os.mkdir(self.path)
        except Exception:
            pass

        print realPath
        os.mknod(realPath+".txt")

# Main
if __name__=='__main__':
    bob = webSiteCompanies()
    bob.createFile()
```

my file is created, but with the name of the error ...

How I can fixe my problem ?

Comment: You didn't called the `self.nameGenerator` function. change it to `self.nameGenerator()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function - `self.nameGenerator()` . Example -

```
realPath = self.path + "/" + str(self.nameGenerator())
```